# Buffer elements based on its contents with comparer function

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In RSJS how to buffer values so buffer will be flushed when next element is different from previous. If elements by some comparator are the same then it should buffer them until next change is detected...

Suppose I have such elements...

```
{ t: 10, price:12 },
{ t: 10, price:13 },
{ t: 10, price:14 },
{ t: 11, price:12 },
{ t: 11, price:13 },
{ t: 10, price:14 },
{ t: 10, price:15 },
```

The elements are the same if `t` property value is the same as previous element `t` value so at the output I just want such buffers...

```
[ { t: 10, price:12 }, { t: 10, price:13}, { t: 10, price:14} ],
[ { t: 11, price:12}, { t: 11, price:13} ],
[ { t: 10, price:14 }, { t: 10, price:15 } ]
```

So in the result I have two elements emited (two buffers each containing the same objects ).

I was trying to use `bufferWhen` or just `buffer` but I don't know how to specify `closingNotifier` in this case because this need to be dependent on elements that are approaching. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR;

```js
const items = [
  { t: 10, price: 12 },
  { t: 10, price: 13 },
  { t: 10, price: 14 },
  { t: 11, price: 12 },
  { t: 11, price: 13 },
  { t: 10, price: 14 },
  { t: 10, price: 15 }
];

const src$ = from(items).pipe(
  delay(0),
  share()
);

const closingNotifier$ = src$.pipe(
  distinctUntilKeyChanged('t'),
  skip(1),
  share({ resetOnRefCountZero: false })
);

src$.pipe(bufferWhen(() => closingNotifier$)).subscribe(console.log);
```

[StackBlitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jq5y6p)

### Detailed explanation

The tricky part was to determine the `closingNotifier` because, as you said, it depends on the values that come from the stream. My first thought was that `src$` has to play 2 different roles: 1) the stream which emits values and 2) the `closingNotifier` for a buffer operator. This is why the `share()` operator is used:

```js
const src$ = from(items).pipe(
  delay(0),
  share()
);
```

`delay(0)` is also used because the source's items are emitted synchronously. And since the source would be subscribed twice(because the source is the stream, but also the `closingNotifier`), its important that both subscribers receive values. If `delay(0)` was omitted, only the first subscriber would receive the items, and the second one would receive nothing, because it was registered after all the source's items have been emitted. With `delay(0)` we just ensure that both subscribers(the first one from the `subscribe` callback and the second one is the **inner subscriber** of `closingNotifier`) are registered before the source emits the value.

Onto `closingNotifier`:

```js
const closingNotifier$ = src$.pipe(
  distinctUntilKeyChanged('t'),
  skip(1),
  share({ resetOnRefCountZero: false })
);
```

- `distinctUntilKeyChanged('t'),` is used because the *signal* that the buffer should emit the accumulated items is when an item with a different `t` value comes from the stream.
- `skip(1)` is used because when the very first value comes from the stream, after the first subscription to the `closingNotifier`, it will cause the buffered items to be sent immediately, which is not what we want, because it is the first batch of items.
- `share({ resetOnRefCountZero: false })` - this is the interesting part; as you've seen, we're using `bufferWhen(() => closingNotifier$)` instead of `buffer(closingNotifier$)`; that is because `buffer` [first subscribes to the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/buffer.ts#L51), and then to the notifier; this complicates the situation a bit so I decided to go with `bufferWhen`, which [subscribes to the notifier first](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/bufferWhen.ts#L75) and then to the source; the *problem* with `bufferWhen` is that it resubscribes the to `closingNotifier` each time after it emits, so for that we needed to use `share`, because we wouldn't like to repeat the logic for the first batch of items(the `skip` operator) when there have already been some items; the problem with `share()`(without the `resetOnRefCountZero` option) is that it will still resubscribe each time after it emits, because that's the default behavior when the *inner* Subject used by `share` is left without subscribers; this can be solved by using `resetOnRefCountZero: false`, which won't resubscribe to the source when the first subscriber is registered, after the inner Subject had been previously left without subscribers;

Comment: Thank You for great explanation. I though it will be simpler but I couldn't find right pipe and operators configurations. Works great. Thank You!

Comment: @MarcinKapusta I'm glad I could help! Please make sure to also mark the answer as accepted, if everything worked alright.